# WordPress blog nginx proxy issue

Tags: wordpress, nginx, proxy, blogs

I am running a blog on blog.example.com. I am using nginx as proxy for example.com/blog. I would like to change word press site URL and word press URL .  When i change site URL preview of post breaks. When i change word press URL WP-admin breaks. When i access example.com/blog/WP-admin it gives a 404 error.

I have tried replacing all the values in database dump file to example.com/blog.  But it didn't help. Also tried to proxy all php file under wp-admin from example.com/blog/ to blog.example.com, Nothing worked.

Anyone can please suggest a solution here.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot exactly know what you mean. Would you mind offering your configuration file here?

And I think your configuration file for nginx proxy would be the code below:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            # other configurations
        }
        location /blog {
            rewrite . /blog/ redirect;
        }
        location /blog/ {
            proxy_pass http://blog.example.com/;
            # the '/' suffix in the url is important
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_forwarded_for;
            # and any other configs
        }
    }
```